# ASP.NET MVC Page Validation Fails (The value is invalid.)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to create ASP.NET MVC Application with Entity Framework, which has One to Many relationship. For that I have successfully managed to load the appropriate list of items to a dropdown control (in Create view), But when I click the Create button (in Create view) page validation is faild, validation error message is `The value '1' is invalid.`.

**Error**

[image]

**Model**

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Person Author { get; set; }
}
```

**DataBaseContext**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasOptional(p => p.Author);
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        PopulateAuthorDropDownList();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Post post)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        PopulateAuthorDropDownList(post.Author);
        return View(post);
    }

    private void PopulateAuthorDropDownList(object selectedPerson = null)
    {
        var personQuery = from d in db.People
                          orderby d.Name
                          select d;
        ViewBag.Author = new SelectList(personQuery, "Id", "Name", selectedPerson);
    }
```

**View**

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Author", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author)
    </div>
```

When I check Author table in database there is Record with Id 1, so I guess 1 is a valid value. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Where do you get that error? Is it an exception? Is it invalid ModelState? Do you have DataAnnotation attributes on your model class?

Comment: @Jan Page.IsValid fails and message is displayed in the view, `ValidationMessageFor` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix this by

changing **Model** to

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public int Author { get; set; } // changed type to int
}
```

changing **View** to

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("AuthorId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author)
    </div>
```

changing **Controller** to

```
private void PopulateAuthorDropDownList(object selectedPerson = null)
    {
        var personQuery = from d in db.People
                          orderby d.Name
                          select d;
        ViewBag.AuthorId = new SelectList(personQuery, "Id", "UserName", selectedPerson); //Changed Author to AuthorId
    }
```

and removing

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasOptional(p => p.Author);
```

from **DataBaseContext**

Anyway Thanks for the answers... :)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show how the `Author` object looks like,

Suppose if it is like this,

```
public class Author
{ 
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Try this,

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Author.Id, ViewBag.Author, "Select an Author")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like this:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Author.Name, (SelectList)ViewBag.AuthorList)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author.Name)
</div>
```

Note that you should name ViewBag.AuthorList instead of ViewBag.Author

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but with this same error message is displayed

Comment: Try removing String.Empty from dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a list of options to `DropDownList` where you are just passing `string.empty`.

And i You should use the strongly typed version `DropDownListFor`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Author.Name, Model.AuthorList)
```

Or maybe even better by not using the name but the Id:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Author.Id, Model.AuthorList)
```

And your model:

```
class Model {
    ...
    public SelectList AuthorList {get;set;}
}
```

And in your controller:

```
model.AuthorList = new SelectList(fetchAuthors()
                         .Select(a => new SelectListItem {
                                          Text = a.Name,
                                          Value = a.Id 
                                      }, "Value", "Text");
```